# Select Time Phase of Dataset with SQLDateTime Objects

Tags: dataset, date-and-time

I have a Dataset like this:

`ds = 
Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date"} -> #] &]@{
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}]}, 
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}]}, 
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2013, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}]}, 
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 8, 19, 40, 0.}]}, 
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 2, 21, 50, 0.}]}, 
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2013, 12, 12, 0, 2, 0.}]}, 
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}]}, 
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2014, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}]},
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 24, 19, 45, 0.}]}, 
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2014, 6, 1, 17, 0, 0.}]}, 
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0.}]},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2014, 1, 23, 20, 50, 0.}]},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}]},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2014, 4, 24, 20, 35, 0.}]},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 4, 22, 0, 0.}]},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2013, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}]}}`

I sort it by date via `ds[SortBy["Date"]]`, then I want to split it up in several Datasets, for each quarter of the year one.

I don't find a working solution for it.
For example
`ds2 = ds[Select[#"Date" >= SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}] &]]` doesn't help,
while the simple comparison
`ds2 = ds[Select[#"Date" == SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}] &]]` works.

I would appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `GroupBy` and `DateValue`.  However, you need to convert your `SQLDateTime`s (from `` Needs["DatabaseLink`"] ``) to standard `DateObject`s.  This can be done on the fly so your dataset keeps the `SQLDateTime` objects.

```
dsResult = 
  ds[
    SortBy["Date"] /* 
    GroupBy[
      DateValue[
       Replace[SQLDateTime[d_] :> DateObject@d]@#"Date", 
       {"Year", "Quarter"}
      ] &
    ]
  ];
```

`RightComposition` (`/*`) is used to `SortBy` and then `GroupBy`. The `GroupBy` function takes the `SQLDateTime` in key (column) `"Date"` and converts it into a `DateObject` by means of `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).  `DateValue` then extracts the year and quarter from the date.

Each group will contain the rows for that quarter.

```
dsResult[All, Dataset]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a result of grouping on the year quarter list, your row keys are now a list containing the year and quarter of the groups.

```
Normal@Keys@dsResult 
(* {{2012, 4}, {2013, 1}, {2013, 2}, {2013, 3}, {2013, 4}, {2014, 1}, {2014, 2}} *)
```

To access a row you must specify the year and quarter in a list **and** place this list in `Key` so *Mathematica* does not confuse it for a part specification.

```
dsResult[Key[{2013, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helps very much indeed! Thank you! The `DateValue` is the key, I was looking for. I will implement your solution, as it is.